# Are example.com/ and example.com/index.html considered same in case of nutch 1.11?

Tags: nutch

I have upgraded my application to nutch 1.11 from nutch 1.3. Previously I used to get 2 urls example.com/ and example.com/index.html while crawling through nutch 1.3.

But after upgradation i have either of two. I want to confirm that Is upgraded nutch is smart enough to detect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutch 1.11 will crawl and index both example.com and example.com/index.html, given that

1. both are included in seeds or reachable via links from one of the seeds
2. URL normalization or filter rules accept both and do not normalize one
3. they are no duplicates (identical content)
4. both of them are real pages and no redirects

Regarding 2: there is a rule in regex-normalize.xml which does the described normalization. By default it's not active (commented out):

```
<!-- changes default pages into standard for /index.html, etc. into /
<regex>
  <pattern>/((?i)index|default)\.((?i)js[pf]{1}?[afx]?|cgi|cfm|asp[x]?|[psx]?htm[l]?|php[3456]?)(\?|&amp;|#|$)</pattern>
  <substitution>/$3</substitution>
</regex> -->
```

Regarding 3: deduplication has been significantly improved for Nutch 1.8 and is now no operation on the index but flags duplicates directly in CrawlDb. However, you should see in the logs that both URLs are fetched, duplication is done later based on the checksum of the fetched content.

Comment: Point 1:Yes they both are reachable and getting fetched.(I have verified in logs)
Point 2: It is commented in my case too.
Point 3: There is duplicate content I guess as both points to index.html
Point 4: As both points to same page.
May because of Identical content, nutch is indexing one of them.
Thanks for your kind help!